# Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/***/***/***": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

Context:

- EKS cluster created in a workspace.
- Need a kubernetes provider to access resources from the eks cluster in another workspace

```
    provider "kubernetes" {
      alias                  = "aws"
      host                   = data.terraform_remote_state.kubernetes.outputs.eks_cluster_endpoint
      cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.kubernetes.outputs.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
      token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
    }
```

Problem:
When running terraform plan/apply `Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/***/***/***": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused` message appeared. This is weird because the field host in the kubernetes provider is not 127.0.0.1:80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- Lose one day of work
- Add `load_config_file=false` to your kubernetes provider block

  ```
     provider "kubernetes" {
      alias                  = "aws"
      host                   = data.terraform_remote_state.kubernetes.outputs.eks_cluster_endpoint
      cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.kubernetes.outputs.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
      token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
      load_config_file       = false
    }
  ```